# How to slow down onclick events inside my function or make them happen gradually? Looking for smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener, slowdown

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this and I just am unable to piece it together... In the event that the link with the id of "light_off" is clicked then I want all the little changes to take place, that part is working, but they're happening too abruptly. How do I slow them down or fade into the changes so the transition looks smoother? Do I fadeIn? Add "slow" duration? Animate? And if so, how would I implement that properly? Gee, I hope that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#lights_off").click(function(){
                $("#lights_off").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#main").addClass(" lights_on");
                $('#flavoredesign_logo').attr('src','img/logofinal.png');
                $("#nav").css("color","#000000");
                $("#nav").css("border-bottom"," #333 solid 1px");

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Would CSS transitions solve your problem? e.g. `#nav {transition: color 2s}` would execute color changes to your nav class over a two seconds window.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [$.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

However using animate you can't set color values, but only numeric values or use 'toggle's. w3 has an excellent guide for using [it](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp).

```
$(function() {
    var on = true;
    $('#lights').on('click', function() {

        if ( on ) {
            $( "#lights" ).animate({
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            }, 1000 );
        } else {
            $( "#lights" ).animate({
                width: 200,
                height: 200
            }, 1000 );
        }
    on = !on;
    });
})
```

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6Le7y2f/3/) with sizing of an element

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout(function(){ /*you code*/ }, 200) or use css animations / transitions

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, couldn't you use the CSS transition attribute to achieve smooth class changes? You can use this to give a time frame for transitioning between different property values. For example, if you wanted to give an animation time frame for transitioning between colours:

```
.light {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: background-color 1s; //Most properties can be manipulated through the transition attribute, e.g. width 1s
```

Then toggling between different classes with different values for background-colour:

```
.lights_off {
    background-color: grey;
}

.lights_on {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/vwrLptma/) that shows how this could be utilised to create a smooth transition.